# Using OpenUI5 view layer similar to Twitter Bootstrap on top of other web application frameworks

Tags: sapui5

Hello UI5 enthusiasts,

I was wondering if it is possible to extract the OpenUI5 view layer in a way similar to Twitters Bootstrap.

The reason is that I work at an SAP partner that creates software outside of the SAP stack. We would like to add the UI5 look and feel to our own web applications though, which are build on Angular and Twitter Bootstrap.

The goal would be to let our customers become attuned to the Fiori look and feel and increase the familiarity of our SAP products. Which could eventually lead to more sales on that side.

But for that we would prefer a light-weight solution. I'm not aware of using the openui5 stack like that, because it needs to load the core and manages the application in its own way.

For that it would be great to have the view components isolated to use them on their own.

Is it possible to do that or would it be an option for the UI5 product team to create a Bootstrap like solution as described above?

Kind regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

from OpenUI5 side, we have some concerns around this approach as there is quite some overlap between Angular and UI5, especially with regards to data binding and MVC. When using the UI5 controls outside the UI5 context, you cannot leverage the main assets that the UI5 data binding adds (some of them are described here  https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0ca956f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html and others like error handling will come soon with 1.28). Still, I'm not saying the combination of UI5 controls with Angular is not possible at all, maybe someone is trying as it is open source but there is an investment needed to close gaps that OpenUI5 already has solved in an excellent manner. On the other hand, it is quite easy to use bootstrap inside UI5 (not Angular). Might that be an option?

What you can examine as well is http://ui5strap.com/. I personally did not yet find the time to assess the approach but it might be worth for you to have a look.

Best regards

Stefan

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it's not about using Bootstrap in UI5 though, it's about using Angular, or as new requirement React for higher performance, and having the UI5 look (and feel).